# JSON 3D element with Three.js and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d

So, I'll try to explain the best I could. I'm developing an application in **React.js**, which I'm learning while I develop this. I now need to have a **3D element** that is a sofa, in my page, the users should be enabled to move and rotate the object with the mouse.
I started using **Three.js** which seemed the best option for what I needed, since the **3D** comes in a **JSON** file that comes from a request to an API accessed by token. So, I'm using **JSONloader** from Three.js to load the JSON file and output it on render function.

This is the error it's on the console right now:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'll leave the code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { ArrowSofa } from './ArrowSofa';

const line = (<Line />);
const mod = <Modulos />;

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

export class Sofa extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            token: {},
            isLoaded: false,
            model: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        /* here are the fetches to have an API response with authentication token */


        fetch(url + '/couch-model/' + this.props.match.params.id + '/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'JWT ' + (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)
            }
        }).then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                model: json,
                isLoaded: true
            }, () => { });
        })
    }

    render() {

        const { model, isLoaded } = this.state;

        if (isLoaded) {

            let json_3d = model.layout_set[0].json_3d;     

            loader.load('url' + json_3d,
                function (geometry, materials) {
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
                    scene.add(mesh);
                });
        }

        if (!isLoaded) {

            return (
                <div id="LoadText">
                    Loading...
                </div>
            )

        } else {

            return (
                <div id="Sofa">
                    <h2>{model.area_set.map(area => area.name)}</h2>
                    <h1>{model.name}</h1>
                    <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>

                    {/* I want to show the 3D model here */}

                    <ArrowSofa
                        handleAddOne={this.handleAddOne}
                        handleLessOne={this.handleLessOne} />

                </div>
            );

        }

    }

}
```

**JSON file:** [jsonblob.com/87e6971a-9a2a-11e8-804a-6546f7c36ad8][2]

So I don't really know what to do now or if I'm putting the code in the right place, anybody can help?
Any doubt ask, I'm here to answer if I wasn't clear enough. Sorry to bother.

**UPDATE** - No erros now, but still don't know if I have any object ready to render

Comment: 'thanks' for deleteing earlier question and answer - I'm sorry that you're still not understand hints - you could ask for later explanations. If you have trouble - breake it down - one component to fetch, one sub-component to show 3d (pass props). You should still create scene outside of render, in lifecycle.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question was already outdated so it didn't make sense...
And then how do I show the object in render? @xadm

Comment: there was a hint about that - creating scene (in lifecycle started [chain of] functions) and attaching to node using ref - I did it, it worked - Did you tried to show any, not loaded, even empty scene using react component? Start with that? Pass loaded data later. And check data, it doesn't look it contains model, I wrote that earlier, too - how many people claiming sth wrong you need?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I just started with three.js yesterday so sorry if my doubts look a bit dumb, I'm just trying to understand the logic of how things work. If you don't want to help, I understand.

Comment: Each of my answers/comments contained hints - if you're not reading/analyzing/learning - you're not helping yourself. Fixing this mess won't help you - start decomposing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it sounds like the JSON that you're receiving from the server might not be properly formatted. Either by checking the Network tab in your DevTools or by logging some of the response string to the console, can you confirm that the data that you get is correctly formatted?

Comment: https://jsonblob.com/87e6971a-9a2a-11e8-804a-6546f7c36ad8 that's the json, can you check that out? @SeanD

Comment: (another) duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724433/show-and-manipulate-element-3d-with-three-js-in-my-react-app

Comment: JSON seems fine, but I think you have two problems.First, that JSON file seems to be describing a texture and not a model, so there won't be any mesh to render. Secondly, calling `loader.load` on the JSON object, which is trying to fetch a URL. See the [reference page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/loaders/JSONLoader) for the JSON Loader and try using `loader.parse` instead.

Comment: ... and making actions in render ? no, no

Comment: I was missing the begining of url, but now I corrected it and the error is the following: https://imgur.com/a/z0nrXqJ

Comment: What happens if you try loading it with `ObjectLoader`?

Comment: I now have something in materials and geometry https://imgur.com/a/iuZNCjv how do I render it? @SeanD

Comment: You need to add your mesh to a scene and render it. Take a look at the [Creating a Scene](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) tutorial to get an idea of what you need for a scene, camera, and lighting. Wherever they use the `cube` variable, you want to use your mesh.